# Checking existence, react conditional and jsx

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, typechecking

I can't help but wonder if there is better way to write this

```
{numberOfStudents && numberOfStudents > 1 && (
          <div>do some jsx</div>

}
```

Is there a way to make this more succinct?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to return the html and then include the function inside the render function.

Answer (score 0):

All three of these return false:

```
console.log(null > 1)
console.log(undefined > 1)
console.log(0 > 1)
```

so you do not need the first condition so long as numberOfStudents is always a number | undefined | null.

```
{numberOfStudents > 1 && <div>...</div>}
```

Alternatively, if you check an array instead of a number value:

```
const students = [];

{students?.length > 1 && <div>...</div>}
```